# Gradle 6.0.1 don't run my Junit class .even though the build is successful after I enter gradle test in windows 10

Tags: gradle

This is my build.gradle file

// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

```
// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
//Gradle wrapper 
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '6.0.1'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ['tst']

dependencies {
// Use JUnit test framework
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
runtime 'junit:junit:4.12'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}
test {

//How to run Gradle test when all tests are UP-TO-DATE?   add below line
      dependsOn 'cleanTest'
    //To enable this fail fast behavior so even a one unit test fail it keeps running 
        failFast = true

    useJUnitPlatform()
      // Give a different location to the gradle html reports in a folder called gradlehtmlReports
    reports.html.enabled = true
    reports.html.setDestination(file("$projectDir/gradlehtmlReports"))
}
```

I have class files in both src/test and src/main folder but neither get picked . When I type gradle  test

```
package com.sam.home;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyClassTest {
     @Test
        void testGet() {
            assertEquals("HelloJUnit 5", "Hello JUnit 5","Text mismatches");
        }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide whether to use JUnit 4 or 5. Right now you are using dependencies from 4 but declaring that you want to use the JUnit *platform*, which is a concept from version 5 only.

If you want to use JUnit 4, remove `useJUnitPlatform()`.

If you want to use JUnit 5, upgrade your dependencies.

Also, instead of the distributionUrl hack for the wrapper, just use `distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL`. And since you are on Gradle 6, you should fix your [deprecated configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) (e.g. change `compile` to `implementation`). I would also advice against using non-standard source directories unless you have very good reasons not to - and personal preferences don't trump long established conventions :-)

And lastly (sorry, I get carried away sometimes), if you want to always execute your unit tests even if they are all successful and up-to-date, you can make the build quicker by not depending on cleaning your project as this will mean you have to recompile your classes even if they haven't changed. So instead of `dependsOn 'cleanTest'`, use `outputs.upToDateWhen { false }`.

Comment: Thank you Bjom . I corrected my project . Also referring official   JUnit 5 helped . https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.4.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle